# Get a user from user name discord py rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I was Making a bot which actually tells you the name of the user who got written in a message
like

```
#message = "hello brother, Akashdeep"
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  msg = "hello brother,"
  if msg in message:
    member = #here i want to get the member object from member name
    await message.channel.send(f"hey {message.author} is calling you, {member.mention}")
```

i tried everything but it dont work , any help is thankful

After Edit : As requested I am sharing my original code

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  #the message that user is tring to input is `85 people are teaming up to rob Gia's bank worth 100,069,420!`
  if messages in message.content:
    print(message.content)

    msg = message.content.split()
    a = msg[10].replace("!","")
    b = msg[7].replace("'s","")
    #print(f'{b}hello')
    channelid  = str(message.channel.id)
    guildid = str(message.guild.id)
    msgid = str(message.id)
    channel = client.get_channel(839479525301551144)
    member = message.guild.get_member_named(b)
    print(member)
    #print(f"{b}hello")
    link = "https://discord.com/channels/"+guildid+"/"+channelid+"/"+msgid
    embed = makeembed("Dank Island™️'s heist history",f"__**Amount**__ : {a}\n__**Holder**__ : {member.mention}\n__**Robbers**__ : {msg[0]}\n __**Status**__ :  [Success]({link})")
    await channel.send(embed=embed)```
````

Comment: "#here i want to get the member object from member name" I don't understand. I don't see anything in your code that represents a member name.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you would want to access the `content` property on `message`, which returns the content, actual "message" of the object.

The `message` object has the context's `guild` in it. The `guild` object has the method `get_member_named` on it.

Since you have a template, you can do `message.content.split(msg)[1]` to get your content.

So now you code will be:

```py
#message = "hello brother, Akashdeep"
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  msg = "hello brother, "
  if msg in message.content:
    member = message.guild.get_member_named(message.content.split(msg)[1])
    # Check if member is None here
    # which is what will be returned if the member was not found
    await message.channel.send(f"hey {message.author} is calling you, {member.mention}")
```

You might need to add intents on your discord bot to allow this to work.

Comment: It gives me AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mention'. did you try it before writing?

Comment: That is why I told you to check if it is None. I believe the issue is that the name of the member you put is not there in the server,

Comment: @GamingwithAkashdeep I actually also tried it with my bot, and [here is the response](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/789089359889825823/875628136191115264/unknown.png)

Comment: The name is actually same letter to letter and even no uppercase is there

Comment: Does the name match *perfectly*? (the case needs to match too). Also note that I added a space at the end of `msg`, which is needed. You can also do `message.content.split(msg)[1].trim()`, which makes it more ergonomic for the user. Also like I said,  you need to give the bot the "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT"

Comment: yup it matched perfectly and also i printed it and its the same lemme see if i can find somethin

Comment: Could you also show what code you are using?

Comment: ok ill edit my question and let you know, its done you can check